# Total of months between two dates returning 0 from diff method

Tags: php, date

I want to get the total of months between two dates. My code is returning `0` rather than `10 * 12` . Why isn't it working and how do I fix it?

Code:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2015-02-14");
$date2 = new DateTime("2025-02-14");
var_dump($date1->diff($date2)->m); // output 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate months between two dates using DateInterval without wrapping within a year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362664/calculate-months-between-two-dates-using-dateinterval-without-wrapping-within-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try this

```
$date1 = '2015-02-14';
$date2 = '2025-02-14';
$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);
$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1); 
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```

> Or Else Try this

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2015-02-14");
$d2 = new DateTime("2025-02-14");
var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->m); // int(4)
var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->m + ($d1->diff($d2)->y*12)); // int(8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2015-02-14");
$date2 = new DateTime("2025-02-14");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo (($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m')) . "months difference";
```